# How does Azure distribute memory to apps using the same service plan?

Tags: azure

I have created a App Service plan in Azure and under that service plan runs 14 applications.
Now that particular service plan has a pricing tier of Standard and Instance Size of Large, which is S3

S3  Cores: 4    RAM: 7 GB   STORAGE:50 GB.

Do these 14 apps share the memory and storage that is available , so only 7G for the 14 apps and 50G of storage for the 14 apps aswell ? If so how can i see how much each is consuming in Azure ?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is Yes, different plans do exist and if an app is a heavy consumer of vCores or Memory then you should isolate it in its own app service plan. Using the quota option from the app service plan it will show how much in total is used and then separately from each app service you can see their storage quota used as well. Now for CPU or Memory it gets a bit complicated as no straightforward way to see this all-in-one place.